# Cannot replace adml file on windows server 2016

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, windows-10

I am trying to follow the CIS guidelines and need a group policy under

```
Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Defender Antivirus\Windows Defender Exploit Guard\Attack Surface Reduction\Configure Attack Surface Reduction Rules.
```

I don't even have a folder called 'Windows Defender Antivirus' just 'Windows Defender'.

Apparently this is included in the 1803 Release Admin Templates called WindowsDefender.adml.

I have added a few adml/admx files with no issues, but I assume I need to replace the old WindowsDefender.adml. Unfortunately I keep getting a 'permission denied error'. I tried to change the permissions, but I get the error 'cannot enumerate permissions'.

My central store is

```
C:\Windows\SYSVOL\sysvol\domain.local\Policies\PolicyDefinitions
```

I have tired to do this both from the DC and on my endpoint. I can add new templates, just not replace any old ones.

Comment: Did you try to delete the file instead of replacing it ?

Comment: I still get a permissions error. I tired changing the ownership of the file to 'Domain Admins' but I still cannot copy or delete the file

Comment: Apparently fixed - I tired updating the permissions again after being made owner and I still got the enumeration error. However, I can now delete files.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used psexec on my DC and opened cmd.exe as system, this allowed me to replace all of my adml and admx files I was having issues with.